# xpath is changing on each automation test run with Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a major issue with Selenium which xpath is changing on each run. For instance, here is the field identifier for a postal code field on a warehouse module (one of the modules that we have in our system):

```
(.//*[@id='warehouseMaintenance:j_idt137_body']/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[4]))
```

it changes to

```
(.//*[@id='warehouseMaintenance:txtZip']))
```

during the execution.

any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: Can you provide little more information with html?

Answer (score 0):

You should assign ID to the postal code field if possible.
Using chain to locate element is not a good practice.

If you have multiple pages and naming convention for each page are different. I suggest you to add a classname to the field, then using cssselector class$='postalcode' to locate the element.
For example, 
`<input type="text" class="xxx yyy warehouseMaintenance postalcode">`

Answer (score -1):

Did U tried using css's? They are not browser dependent. 
U could use cssify to change your xpath's to css's or get it from browser.